# Github remove "Local Pull Request Branches"

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm struggling with **GitHub Pull Requests and Issues** in vscode. Under Local Pull Request Branches I see an ancient pull request that was merged successfully some time ago. This pull request is no longer needed but apparently according to VScode still in review mode. If I attempt to Exit Review Mode I see "The default branch is already checked out."

How do I get rid of this unneeded local pull request branch? Btw. git branch shows, save for the master branch, an empty list and `Close Pull Request` is grayed out.

Comment: I did a reclone of the same repo and this local pull request did not show up. Could this be a bug in GitHub Pull Requests and Issues?

Comment: Same issue here, was this ever solved without having to re-clone the repo.
like you said seems like a bug. the weird thing is online videos do not have this same issue.

Comment: I also had this issues.

For me I had created a pull request from my dev branch into main. After merging the PR I rebased my dev branch on to main and was unable to get the old PR to go away from the 'Local Pull Request Branches' section.

I was able to fix it by deleting my dev branch and just recreating it (instead of rebasing on main) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯